Powershel script to pull task history data
With the below PowerShell scripts, I am able to export all the scheduled task data in csv format but it does not include the task history data. I want to include 'Task Triggered on Scheduler' and 'Task Completed' which is available in task history.
$outputDirectory = "\\COM\Data\MI\MI\Download\Supporting Files\Data"

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $outputDirectory)) {
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $outputDirectory
}

$currentUsername = $env:USERNAME

schtasks /query /fo csv /v | Out-File -FilePath "$outputDirectory\$currentUsername.csv"

Write-Host "Tasks exported to $outputDirectory\$currentUsername.csv"


As outlined in this answer, you would need to query the EventLog to obtain the history for the events.
The Get-WinEvent returns a lot of information, but we can use the -FilterHashTable argument to filter the results to something meaningful. If you were to navigate to the EventViewer at "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/Operational" and review the Details / XML View for the "Task Category" items you're interested in, you would notice that the EventID for the following:

Task triggered on scheduler: 107
Task completed: 102


The following uses the Get-ScheduledTask PowerShell cmdlet to return all the scheduled tasks, which is the similar to the schtasks command except it returns objects that we can further manipulate in PowerShell.
// interesting task EventIds
$eventIds = @( 107, 102 )

// obtain a list of tasks, similar to schtasks
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask

// loop through each task, grabbing the events
$tasks | ForEach-Object {

   // create the full name for the task
   $taskName = $_.TaskPath + $_.TaskName

   // build a hashtable that contains our query parameters
   $query = @{
     Path = "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational"
     TaskName = $taskName
     Id = $eventIds
   }

   // obtain the list of events for this task
   $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable $query |
         // simplify the list to include timestamp, id and displayName
         Select TimeCreated, Task, TaskDisplayName

   // modify the task by adding the history of events as a new property
   $_ | Add-Member -Name "History" -Value $events -MemberType NoteProperty
}

You now have a detailed object that contains all the tasks and their associated history. You could persist as JSON or you could loop through it again to produce a CSV with the values you're interested in.
